# display flex together with transform rotate

Tags: css, responsive-design, flexbox, css-transforms

I have an online scorecard for the game qwixx using **"display: flex"** and "vmin" for margins and font sizes. So it use the complete viewport and is pretty responsive.

But my problem is the portrait mode for smartphones/tablets and the missing possibility to force the landscape mode by a webpage.

If a user locked his orientation or use an app to show the page which doesn't support landscape mode (e.g. barcoo), I want to give him also on portrait mode the scorecard in landscape orientation.

So I tried **"transform: rotate(90deg)"**.

The rotation works pretty well, but the responsive scaling not. It seems the browser don't consider the rotation for the calculation of the width and height of the flex layout.

The relevant CSS I use:

```
html, body, .container-fluid {
  height: 100%;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  height: calc(100% / 6);
}

.btn {
  flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
}

body {
  webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}

@media all and (orientation:portrait) {
  body {
    webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
}
```

Someone already raised in this problem and give me a hint how to solve this? Or can give me a hint for an alternative solution?

**The desired behavior is: on portrait modus the page should rotate 90deg by keep the responsive scaling behavior of the flexbox using the complete viewport.**

Comment: The link doesn't work. That's precisely why link-only questions are not allowed, you must include all necessary code in the question itself.

Comment: Why the link does not work for you? I will try to make a jsfiddle and to extract all of the needed html/css for the question.

Comment: Oh, I see, I must wait like 10 seconds before the link loads. But I still don't understand the desired behavior.

Comment: Oh, thats right, sry. Its a test app instance of heroku, if it sleeps because of not having load in the last minutes, the first page load needs some seconds.

The desired behavior is: portrait modus should rotate the page 90deg by keep the responsive scaling behavior of the flexbox.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a solution, the important and missing declarations in my css example was:

- Rotate around a defined corner (transform-origin)
- Set the position absolute and because of the rotate with an offset (90deg = left: 100vw)
- Exchange height and width definitions

So the changed relevant css looks now like:

```
.row {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  height: calc(100vh / 6);
}

.btn {
  flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
}

@media all and (orientation:portrait) {
  .container-fluid {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform-origin: top left;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform-origin: top left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 100vw;
    width: 100vh;
    height: 100vw;
  }

  .row {
    height: calc(100vw / 6);
  }
}
```

This works pretty well. The only missing thing is now the iOS problem they don't sub the size of the status bar from the viewport size.
But thats a known problem with existing solutions, so I'm think that is solveable.

You can test this here: http://dqwixx-staging.herokuapp.com/ (care about the page view maybe need some seconds) with a browser window (larger high as width) or a smartphone/tablet in portrait mode.